# Действительно ли в .pyd файле не хранится исходный код?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython

У меня в программе используются некоторые файлы, которые я написал на Cython и которые хранятся в формате `.pyd`.

В одном из таких файлов (в исходной версии (`.pyx`)), в классе `lcchk`, в функции `init_checker` прописан `input()` на 152 строчке.

.pyx файлов с исходным кодом нет в одной директории с запускаемым файлом, однако, если прервать программу с помощью `Ctrl-C`, она выдаст ошибку, в которой точно укажет строчку. Более того, в ошибке указан файл lchk.pyx, хотя в папке проекта нет `.pyx` файлов. Из-за чего это может быть?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\main.py", line 204, in <module>
    checker.init_checker()
  File "lchk.pyx", line 152, in lchk.lcchk.init_checker
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Часть кода из lchk.pyx:

```
cdef class lcchk:
    cdef str a
    cdef b
    cdef str c
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = "some_string"
        self.b = somemodule.someclass()
        self.c = "some another str"

    def init_checker(self):
        while True:
            input_data = input("Введите что-нибудь: ")
```

Код из запускаемого скрипта main.py:

```
import lchk

test = lchk.lcchk()
test.init_checker()
```

setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(ext_modules=cythonize("lchk.pyx"))
```

Comment: Информация для дебага. Можно её убрать выставив соответсвующие ключи компилятора. Всего исходного кода там нет.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13143294/1016033